battery recalibration needed: energy-full is twice energy-full-design
I got a new battery from an online provider, unfortunately in retrospect I am doubtful that they ship quality material.
However the battery appears to give a decent autonomy to the laptop (Asus X550 running Debian), but it needs recalibration, as showned by upower --monitor-detail (selected lines):
energy:              76.455 wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         91.995 Wh
energy-full-design:  44.25 Wh
percentage:          83%
capacity:            100%

energy-full is twice as much as energy-full-design, as if it could be charged at 200% ...
Also when unplugged and going down to ~50%, the laptop actually runs out of power.
So it seems like I should just decrease the values of energy-full and energy by about 45 or 50 Wh.
How to do that? There are corresponding files in /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/{energy_full,energy_full_design,energy_now}, are they read-only?
I saw mentions of tlp recalibrate, but this seems geared towards ThinkPads, is it worth trying?

Other lines of output from upower:
rechargeable:   yes
energy-rate:    22.185 W
voltage:        15 V
charge-cycles:  435
time to full:   42.0 minutes
technology:     lithium-ion

